# How to increment value in multiple fields and multiple documents in mongodb in one query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an object which is representing a lesson

```
 {
    "_id": "62ad8ac4a5523541d78df217",
    "lessonID": "35d02fc5-94dd-48e7-a315-7dcea6ac6806",
    "teachers": [
        "629232d2fc8fa8646b21cf3d"
    ],
    "students": [
        "62924d0a6055ad4d2533577b"
    ],
    "subject": "English",
    "start": 1655515800000,
    "end": 1655517600000,
    "roomNumber": "3",
    "venue": "Elmwood Park",
    "attendance": [
        "62924d0a6055ad4d2533577b"
    ],
    "paid": false,
    "__v": 0
},
```

what i'm trying to do is to find all documents with the same "lessonID" and update "start" and "end" (timestamps).

I'd like to increment or decrease values by a certain amount on every document

I've been sitting on it for a while and I thought about doing this:

- finding all documents that match my query
- deleting all found documents
- mapping through the array
- inserting the mapped array of documents

it sounds extremely inefficient tho (and it causes duplicate or loss of data if any of the steps fail)... there must be a better way to do that.

Comment: Why are you deleting? Why can't you just use $inc with +ve, -ve values?

Comment: thanks! I didn't know about this new operator. Was experimenting with bulkWrite() but it does not take the createMany().  $inc sounds like the most sensible thing to do. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

As @Gibbs suggested, simply use `$inc`:

```
db.collection.update({
  "lessonID": "35d02fc5-94dd-48e7-a315-7dcea6ac6806"
},
{
  $inc: {start: amountStartInc, end: amountEndInc}
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5ekAPBoiN0F)